# How to let canvas/svg circle on image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have some problem on draw circle on image, and I hope I can do something like this picture.
(from http://www.kinhub.org/kinmap/index.html)

[draw circle on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVkxa.png)

I'm trying to do that but fail like this code, circle cannot cover on image and I have no idea to deal with this problem, please help me or give me some keyword to search.

```js
var img = document.getElementById("Kinome_tree");
var c = document.getElementById("circle");
c.style.position = "absolute";
c.style.left = img.offsetLeft;
c.style.top = img.offsetTop;

var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(0,50,10,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#00ff00';
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<img id="Kinome_tree" src="https://media.cellsignal.com/www/images/science/kinases/kinome.jpg" border="0" width="300">
<canvas id="circle"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Kindly add + "px"** where you are setting your left and right with offsets

> Below is the fixture:

```js
var im = document.getElementById("Kinome_tree");
var c = document.getElementById("circle");
c.style.position = "absolute";
c.style.left = im.offsetLeft + "px";
c.style.top = im.offsetTop + "px";

var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(0,50,10,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#00ff00';
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<img id="Kinome_tree" src="https://media.cellsignal.com/www/images/science/kinases/kinome.jpg" border="1" width="300">
<canvas id="circle"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works:)
However when I use this on my website have some problem, and I find that circle cannot show when I add navbar ... exactly submenu navbar. I don't know how to solve this problem, please help me again.

[Add Navbar Code](https://codepen.io/machia04541333/pen/xxGYOQw)
I mark the **problem code** by annotation `<!--HERE-->` and when I annotation there it is work. Thanks a lot : )

Comment: i need to see the code for that.. must be something is missing !!

Answer (score 1):

***1.*** As already mentioned, you should add `px` to offset top and left

***2.*** I not see a reason at all to move the canvas around - have the canvas cover the whole image, and draw the circle/circles at the specified positions/size

***3.*** The first 2 parameters of `arc` is the `centerX` and `centerY`.so by given `0` you cut the circle by half

***4.*** From the image you provided its look like you want to `fill` the circle. not `stroke`. so you should use `fill` function

I recommend do something like this:

```js
var im = document.getElementById("Kinome_tree");
var c = document.getElementById("circle");
c.style = "position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;display:block";

im.onload = function(){
  c.width = im.offsetWidth;
  c.height = im.offsetHeight;
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(50,50,10,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
#image-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
#Kinome_tree {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-container">
<img id="Kinome_tree" src="https://media.cellsignal.com/www/images/science/kinases/kinome.jpg" border="1" width="300">
<canvas id="circle"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works:) However when I use this on my website have some problem, and I find that circle cannot show when I add navbar ... exactly submenu navbar. I don't know how to solve this problem, please help me again. [Add Navbar Code](https://codepen.io/machia04541333/pen/xxGYOQw) I mark the problem code by annotation `<!--HERE-->` and when I annotation there it is work. Thanks a lot : )

Comment: I think the image cached, and the `onload` not called. I made some changes. please see the link

Comment: Thanks for your help but I want to know why use `ctx.closePath()`